dead-letter publication using bytes in schama, I need avro
I have some problem-I have application in SpringBoot and I am using Kafka with retries. I have producer who avro compatibiled message to my topic and I have consumer to consume this message. It works but I have on my consumer set retries-it works like that that messege it goes to the main topic, then, according to the number of retries, it goes to the retry topic, and when the pool of retries is exhausted, it goes to the dlt topic. I have auto.register.schemas set to true and here is the problem - when accessing the main topic or the retry topic, everything is OK, but when trying to send a message to dlt I have the error: .RestIncompatibleSchemaException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject , In fact, when I try to view the schemas, for the main topic and retry they are ok, and for the dlt topic it looks like this: "schema":"\"bytes\"". Does anyone know why the schemas for the main topic are registered OK, but not for the DLT topic, and where does this error come from?
I try somehow set DeadLetterPublisher but I dont know how to do it for dlt.

We started seeing the same behavior recently. As there was no change in our project, we suspect this problem is due to a Confluent update/change.
So for the time being, we manually applied our schema on retry & DLT topics to work around the issue. If we do not set the schema, this is what was getting applied to our DLT topic.

